# MapStruct different implementations: mvn install vs run

Tags: java, spring, maven, mapstruct

I've a Spring Boot 2.2 project. I'm using MapStruct 1.3.1 and Lombook 1.18.12.

I've these models:

```
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Persistable<Long>, Serializable {

//stuff
}
```

+

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "AuditLog")
@EntityListeners(AuditLogListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class AuditLog extends AbstractEntity {
//stuff
}
```

+

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "AuditCdr")
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class AuditCdr extends AuditLog {

    @Size(max = 30)
    private String from;

    @Size(max = 30)
    private String to;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Size(max = 50)
    private CallType callType;

    private Instant startDate;

    private Instant endDate;

    public AuditCdr() {
        setOperationType(AuditType.CDR);
    }
}
```

I created this DTO:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Cdr3CXDto {

    String from;

    String to;

    String type;

    String startDate;

    String endDate;

    Long contactId;
}
```

and this mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface Cdr3CXMapper {


    @ValueMappings({
            @ValueMapping(source = "Inbound", target = "INBOUND"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "Outbound", target = "OUTBOUND"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "Missed", target = "MISSED"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "Notanswered", target = "NOT_ANSWERED")
    })
    @Mapping(source = "contactId", target = "parentId")
    @Mapping(source = "type", target = "callType")
    AuditCdr cdr3CXDtoToAuditCdr(Cdr3CXDto cdr3CXDto);
}
```

This is my relevan part of pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I also added dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I run mvn install, mapstructs generate the right implementation for the mapper:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-04-30T14:09:56+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class Cdr3CXMapperImpl implements Cdr3CXMapper {

    @Override
    public AuditCdr cdr3CXDtoToAuditCdr(Cdr3CXDto cdr3CXDto) {
        if ( cdr3CXDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AuditCdr auditCdr = new AuditCdr();

        auditCdr.setFrom( cdr3CXDto.getFrom() );
        auditCdr.setTo( cdr3CXDto.getTo() );
        if ( cdr3CXDto.getStartDate() != null ) {
            auditCdr.setStartDate( Instant.parse( cdr3CXDto.getStartDate() ) );
        }
        if ( cdr3CXDto.getEndDate() != null ) {
            auditCdr.setEndDate( Instant.parse( cdr3CXDto.getEndDate() ) );
        }

        return auditCdr;
    }
}
```

No compiling errors, it's ok. When I do run a JunitTest as in the image, I have a compiling error because the implementation is wrong this time:

[image]

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-04-30T15:09:29+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class Cdr3CXMapperImpl implements Cdr3CXMapper {

    @Override
    public AuditCdr cdr3CXDtoToAuditCdr(Cdr3CXDto cdr3CXDto) {
        if ( cdr3CXDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AuditLogBuilder<?, ?> auditCdr = AuditLog.builder();

        auditCdr.parentId( cdr3CXDto.getContactId() );

        return auditCdr.build();
    }
}
```

It seems MapStruct uses the builder from the parent class and not the child as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929524/mapstruct-generated-class-uses-lombok-builder-from-parent-instead-of-child). I hope there is a way to instruct mapstruct to generate the right code even when I run a single test in my IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference between the execution of the compilation from Maven or from IntelliJ. If there is a difference it might mean that there is some problem with the Lombok `@SuperBuilder`.

I would try to add the `printProcessorInfo` and `printRounds` compiler arguments so that you can see what is happening.